# HTML/CSS Parent-child not getting full width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the width of the blue nav bar to cover the all of my container/parent area. As you see I have left and-right a 100px? gap. I want to cover that with me navigation bar.

Seems the position relative wont work. thanks[See the picture bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH46n.png)

```css
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  color:#FFF;
}

.content
{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
nav
{
    font-size: 0;
    
}

nav .menu li

{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

nav .menu li a

{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
   
  

}

nav .menu li a:hover
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for reviewing code or writing it for you... here is a site for on-the-point question about programming in general. If you want your code reviewed you can try asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: However, if you have a specific problem or error you are getting, consider rephrasing your post to reflect so, as for now it seems you are asking for us to review/write your code and that could result in several downvotes or your question being closed. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Your `nav` already spans the entire width, but you can't see it as it has no background color. The blue comes from the `a` tags, which have a specified `width`

Comment: Yes, you might apply the blue background color to the `<nav>` or `<ul>` element rather than the individual `<a>` elements.

Comment: But yes, you may want to have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future guidance.

Comment: im so sorry this is my first time using the Question section.Won't happen again thanks for your time guys.I understand

Comment: please explain in detail code is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I've amended your code, the nav should now span the entire width. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

https://jsfiddle.net/ofbnaks7/1/

I've added `position: relative; width: 100%;` ensuring, that each list item spans the width of the list, its parent. Next, since you have anchors inside your list items, I set `display: block; width: 100%;` to ensure that they display in the correct place and fill their parent's width. Also, I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the anchors. Since you had padding on your anchors, this means that the padding will be 'inside' the width of 100%, not outside, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Especially with new coders, it's very important to explain what you did. Just providing the code is [not in line with SO philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I've explained this in detail above, thank's for helping to improve my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, you might consider [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).
Here's a [handy guide](http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/).

> The defining aspect of the flex layout is the ability to alter its items' width and/or height to best fit in the available space on any display device. A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow ... Block layout is vertically-biased; inline layout is horizontally-biased. Flexbox layout permits either.

Below, I've turned your `<ul>` element into a flexible box container, so that all the children together fill the horizontal space. I've allowed the menu items to wrap to multiple lines when necessary. I've also set your `<a>` elements to be `display:block` so that each fills the width of its parent `<li>`.

```css
.content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Note the [browser compatibility of Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

---

You could also use the `display:table-cell` method you started to implement. Similarly, the key is setting the `<a>` elements to `display:block` so their backgrounds cover the width of their parents.

```css
.content {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

---

But the simplest solution might be to move the blue background color from your `<a>` elements to the `<ul>` or `<nav>` element:

```css
.content {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav .menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

nav .menu li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and im sorry for my stupid question. I'll read more about flexbox :) i wanted to keep it simple but,i guess i have to pay more attention next time! I can't  vote yet, but thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries. It's not a stupid question and your original method will work, too. (Basically, the elements with the blue background have fixed widths and don't fill the red space.) Flex is just an alternative layout style.